# Unable to display item from microsoft sql server out on gridview via dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm not able to display out the values i have added into my SQL database. Here is my code i have used. The initial idea was when the user entered the particular page , by default it will display out all the values in a form of a gridview. Hence, i put my SQL connection code in the page_load. I have tested my connection at the server explorer and it says ping test succeeded.

My SQL connection

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Page.IsPostBack == false)
        {

        SqlConnection connSel = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost;" + "Initial Catalog = project; Integrated Security = SSPI");

        SqlDataAdapter adapSel;

        string mySQL = "Select * from Report";

        adapSel = new SqlDataAdapter(mySQL, connSel);

        connSel.Open();

        DataSet dsSel = new DataSet();
        adapSel.Fill(dsSel);
        GWCase.DataSource = dsSel;
        GWCase.DataBind();

        connSel.Close();

    }
    }
```

Here is my source code for my gridview.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GWCase" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Width="100%" BackColor="#CCCCCC"  BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" ForeColor="Black"     Height="199px" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GWCase_SelectedIndexChanged">

    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
  </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your gridview `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` so gridview not generate column automatically. And in your grid view code I didn't see any `BoundField` OR `TemplateField` for which it generate column i.e. your grid view doesn't have any columns to show. So better to Set `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` or define some `BoundField` OR `TemplateField`. I think it will work than.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this? just Open the connection before using it.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(Page.IsPostBack == false)
            {

            SqlConnection connSel = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost;" + "Initial Catalog = project; Integrated Security = SSPI");

            connSel.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter adapSel;

            string mySQL = "Select * from Report";

            adapSel = new SqlDataAdapter(mySQL, connSel);

            DataSet dsSel = new DataSet();
            adapSel.Fill(dsSel);
            GWCase.DataSource = dsSel;
            GWCase.DataBind();

            connSel.Close();

        }
        }
```

Comment: it's still the same. no value is being displayed out on my gridview.

Comment: try to use your query in the sql. see if there will be returning values.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime long before I was working on tables and dataset. I am not sure, but I think each dataset holds number of tables and when you try select a particular table from your database and fill up, it stores in the first table of dataset. Try setting datasource as:

```
GWCase.DataSource = dsSel.Tables[0];
```